# Atributos do objeto vindo nullo na Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query, expressões-lambda

Alguém saberia me informar o porque que na minha consulta, os atributos do objeto COR, estão vindo null?
faço essa mesma consulta para Tamanhos, e me trás o resultado esperando.
porém, ao fazer a mesma consulta, para a classe Cor, ele encontra os objetos, porém trás as informações nulla.

[image: Imagem da consulta da classe Tamanho]
[image: Imagem da Consulta da Classe Cor]

A query para buscar o Produto:

```
Produto produto = db.ProdutoDb.Find(id);
```

A query Tamanhos

```
   var geral = db.ProdutoDb
                                    .Where(x => x.CodProduto == produto.CodProduto)
                                    .Select(x => x.Tamanho)
                                    .ToList();
```

A query Cor:

```
var Cores = db.ProdutoDb
                                    .Where(x => x.CodProduto == produto.CodProduto)
                                    .Select(x => x.Cor)
                                    .ToList();
```

A classe Cor:

```
 public class Cor
    {
        [Key]
        public int CorId{ get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }
```

A classe Tamanho:

```
public class Tamanho
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Descricacao { get; set; }
    }
```

A classe Produto:

```
public class Produto
    {
        public Produto()
        {
            this.Categoria = new HashSet<Categoria>().ToList();
        }

        #region Atributos
        [Key]
        public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="o nome deve ser preenchido")]
        public string NomeDoProduto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "o codigo deve ser preenchido")]
        public string CodProduto { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="o preço deve ser preenchido")]
        public decimal PrecoDeAtacado { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "o preço deve ser preenchido")]
        public decimal PrecoDeVarejo { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1200)]
        public string Informacoes { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1200)]
        public string Decricao { get; set; }
        public bool? Disponibilidade { get; set; }
        public int Quatidade { get; set; }


        #endregion

        #region Chaves Estrangeiras
        public int CorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Cor Cor { get; set; }
        public int TamanhoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tamanho Tamanho { get; set; }
        public int ImagemId { get; set; }
        public virtual Imagem Imagem { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Comentario> Comentario { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Categoria> Categoria { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

O interesante, é que as cores estão cadastradas e aparecendo na lista normalmente, a consulta até me retorna resultado, porém, com atributos nullo, ou seja, Id e Descrição não vem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esses objetos não estão sendo carregados provavelmente por que você não usou o `ICollection<T>` para informar que quer fazer o Lazy Loading.

Provavelmente o `Tamanho` deve estar vindo nulo também.

Adicione as seguintes linhas nessas classes e veja se funciona:

```
public class Cor
{
    [Key]
    public int CorId{ get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> { get; set; }
}

public class Tamanho
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Descricacao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> { get; set; }
}
```

Outro detalhe é que você não usou o `DataAnnotations` para explicitar a relação entre as entidades `Tamanho` e `Cor` com Produto:

```
[ForeignKey("CorId")]
public virtual Cor Cor { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Id")]
public virtual Tamanho Tamanho { get; set; }
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelPassos que bom! Marque como resposta quando possível que poderá ajudar outras pessoas. :)

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem certeza que cor existe talvez seja algo relacionado a lazy loading, você pode tentar forçar esse carregamento usando `include`, exemplo:

```
var Cores = db.ProdutoDb
                                    .Where(x => x.CodProduto == produto.CodProduto)
                                    .Include(x=>x.Cor)
                                    .Select(x => x.Cor)
                                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Não sei pq, mas o INCLUDE, não funciona depois da clausula WHERE. mas de qualquer forma eu ja consegui, muito obrigado.